# How to apply Custom Transform Orientation as a Local Transform

Tags: transforms

I've created a custom Transform Orientation (named *Side*). I also have an object `A` in which the Local Transform Orientation is set to Global Transform Orientation. I want object `A`'s Local Transform Orientation to be equal to *Sides* Orientation. How do I do that?
I would prefer a manual solution, but one using Python would work too.

I did some digging and found that You can set Transform Orientation in `bpy.context.screen.areas[?].spaces[0].transform_orientation` but it is just an enum with the name of a active transform. Where is the quaternion stored?

Comment: What do you mean with 'local transform orientation' that is set to 'Global Transform orientation', because these are the different options right?

Comment: If You create an object its rotation is set to [0,0,0] (and this matches the world orientation) and location to 3Dcursor position. If You will rotate the object it's local rotation will be set to that amount (i.e. [0,0,45]), but the mesh is rotated too. So let's say _Side_ transform is [0, 0, 90]. I want my object to be rotated +[0, 0, 90] and the mesh to be rotated +[0, 0, -90] so that it looks like it wasn't rotated, yet it local rotation to be [0, 0, 90]. You can think of it as rotation of local transform of an object instead of object itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I discovered while working on [Blender function to transform a selected edge along a custom axis](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/41281/blender-function-to-transform-a-selected-edge-along-a-custom-axis/41439#41439) the transforms are stored in `bpy.context.scene.orientations[i].matrix`.  You can use `orientations[0]` or `orientations[name]`.

If you want the rotation component as a quaternion use `orientations[i].matrix.to_quaternion()` .

Answer (score 3):

With your custom transform selected and in Object Mode, turn on "Affect only > Origins" in the Tool sidebar panel.

[image]

Then, you can go to Object > Transform > Align To Transform Orientation. Done!