# Script for automatic re-aligning objects to make linked-duplicates

Tags: modeling, python, scripting, linked-data, transform-orientation

I have over 1000 copies of a given reference object.
Translations and rotations have been applied to all copies.

Unfortunately, I haven't used 'linked duplicate'
and in order to make all 1000 objects use the reference mesh I could do the following:

```
for each selected Object{
    set 'origin to geometry'
    select the face with biggest area in its mesh
    make a custom orientation from this face
    goto Tool > Options > turn on 'Affect only > Origins' (see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/41493/how-to-apply-custom-transform-orientation-as-a-local-transform)
    use 'Align To Transform Orientation' to set the local orientation to the custom one
    in object data porperties > set mesh data to the reference mesh
}
```

This works (in Blender 3.3.4) but will take me a week to do it manually.

Does anybody know the commands to make a script of this? Thanks in advance folks!

Edit: A tortuous solution using 'Suzanne' as reference:

```
import bpy
import numpy as np

def get_largest_face_inx(obj):
    areas = [poly.area for poly in obj.data.polygons]
    return np.argmax(areas)

selected_objects = bpy.context.selected_objects

# Iterate through all objects in selection
for obj in selected_objects:
    bpy.ops.object.origin_set(type='ORIGIN_GEOMETRY') # center
    inx = get_largest_face_inx(obj) # get face
    obj.data.polygons[inx].select = True
    bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = obj # make object active
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
    bpy.ops.transform.create_orientation(name='a', overwrite = True)
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
    bpy.context.scene.transform_orientation_slots[0].type = "a" # set 'a' as orientation 
    m = bpy.context.scene.transform_orientation_slots[0].custom_orientation.matrix # 3x3 matrix

    bpy.ops.object.add_named(linked=True, name='Suzanne') # add Suzanne object
    s = bpy.context.object # take
    s.location = obj.location # translate
    s.matrix_world = m.to_4x4() # rotate
    s.location = obj.location # translate
```